# Why can I only connect to my printer when ethernet is disconnected?

Tags: networking, printing

I have a printer connected to a wired network 10.23.161.x that is connected to a wireless network 10.171.240.x. I can print fine when connected to this wireless network from my Ubuntu 14.04 workstation. However, when I connect to a different and separate wired network 10.23.174.x that is not connected to either of the previous networks I am unable to print. As soon as I disconnect my wired connection, I am able to print. I tried different printing protocols including AppSocket, LPD and IPP but this does not seem to make a difference.

Is there a way to avoid disconnecting from my separate wired network simply to print? Can I specify a network adapter or path for this printer somehow?

Comment: Can you get response from any host of `10.23.161.x` from `10.23.174.x` via `ping`  and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Ubuntu favours the ethernet connection when resolving the address. 
This means that when you try to reach 10.23.161.x, you get the 'outside' connection; your traffic is blocked by 10.23.161.x's router firewall.

If you can use the printer's internal (private) address through the wireless network, you could try the solution from 
https://superuser.com/questions/216678/ubuntu-network-priority/217510#217510 :

Right click the network icon -> Edit connections -> wlan0 [or whatever your wireless interface is called] -> ipv4 Settings -> Routes...

Tick the box with "Use this connection only for resources on its network"

After 'OK'-ing and 'Apply'-ing your way through all opened dialog boxes, you should be able to print while being connected to the wired network.
(Except perhaps if both the wired and wireless network use the same private network space (e.g. both use 192.168.002.xxx). If this is the case, and you still can't print, you might try checking whether one of the routers supports changing its network space.)

Comment: This does not seem to help and I suspect that is because the printer is not on the same subnet as the wireless network but is connected to the wireless network and so this is my struggle.

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel Which ip address do you use for the printer? Is it a 10.23.161.xxx address or a private address?

Comment: The printer has IP address 10.23.161.xxx on a wired network that is also connected to the wireless network 10.171.240.xxx that my Ubuntu workstation is connected to. This all works fine until I connect my workstation to a separate wired network.